# Animating circular progress view (timer) in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, animation, timer

I have got this code for a circular progress view, which displays the progress for how far through a timer you are e.g. You set the timer at 60 seconds and the progress bar is halfway when you reach 30 seconds. The code is show below:

```
import UIKit

class TimerCircularProgressView: UIView {

@IBInspectable var timeSeconds:CGFloat = CGFloat(timers.seconds[timers.timerID]) {
    didSet {
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}

@IBInspectable var timeLabelString:String = "" {
    didSet {
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}


private var startAngle = CGFloat(-90 * Double.pi / 180)
private var endAngle = CGFloat(270 * Double.pi / 180)

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setup()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setup()
}

private func setup() {
    backgroundColor = .clear
}

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    // General Declarations
    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
        return
    }

    // Colour Declarations
    let progressColour = UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    let progressBackgroundColour = UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0.4)
    // let titleColour = UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0.8) // let titleColour = UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0.8)

    // Shadow Declarations
    let innerShadow = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.22)
    let innerShadowOffset = CGSize(width: 3.1, height: 3.1)
    let innerShadowBlurRadius = CGFloat(4)

    // Background Drawing
    let backgroundPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY, width: rect.width, height: rect.height))
    backgroundColor?.setFill()
    backgroundPath.fill()

    // ProgressBackground Drawing
    let progressPadding = CGFloat(timers.deviceWidth / 32 * 1.5) // 15
    print(progressPadding)
    print(timers.deviceWidth)

    let progressBackgroundPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: rect.minX + progressPadding/2, y: rect.minY + progressPadding/2, width: rect.size.width - progressPadding, height: rect.size.height - progressPadding))
    progressBackgroundColour.setStroke()
    progressBackgroundPath.lineWidth = timers.deviceWidth / 32 // 5, 10
    progressBackgroundPath.stroke()

    // Progress Drawing
    let progressRect = CGRect(x: rect.minX + progressPadding/2, y: rect.minY + progressPadding/2, width: rect.size.width - progressPadding, height: rect.size.height - progressPadding)
    let progressPath = UIBezierPath()
    progressPath.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: progressRect.midX, y: progressRect.midY), radius: progressRect.width / 2, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: (endAngle - startAngle) * (CGFloat(timers.seconds[timers.timerID]/timers.seconds[timers.timerID])  - (timeSeconds / CGFloat(timers.seconds[timers.timerID]))) + startAngle, clockwise: true)
    progressColour.setStroke()
    progressPath.lineWidth = timers.deviceWidth / 32 * 0.8 // Thickness of the progress line
    progressPath.lineCapStyle = CGLineCap.round
    progressPath.stroke()

    // Text Drawing
    let textRect = CGRect(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY, width: rect.size.width, height: rect.size.height)
    let textContent = NSString(string: timeLabelString)
    let textStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle.default.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableParagraphStyle
    textStyle.alignment = .center

    let textFontAttributes = [
        NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: rect.width / timers.timerFontSize)!, // 3, HelveticaNeue-Light
        NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.black, // NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: titleColor,
        NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle: textStyle]

    let textHeight = textContent.boundingRect(with: CGSize(width: textRect.width, height: textRect.height), options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: textFontAttributes, context: nil).height

    context.saveGState()
    context.clip(to: textRect)
    textContent.draw(in: CGRect(x: textRect.minX, y: textRect.minY + (textRect.height - textHeight) / 2, width: textRect.width, height: textHeight), withAttributes: textFontAttributes)
    context.restoreGState();
}

}
```

Currently, the circular progress bar updates every seconds, which means that for short time periods, the animation of the progress section moving is jumpy, and not smooth.

I have tried setting up a timer of about 0.05 second intervals, but this can give inaccurate timings, and so I have tried 0.1 and 0.2, which still appear fairly jumpy.

```
@objc func processSlider() {

    if secondsDDecimal > 0 {
        secondsDDecimal -= 0.2
    }

    circularProgressView.timeSeconds = CGFloat(secondsDDecimal)

}
```

Is there a way to animate the transition of the circular progress view second by second, so that it is smooth and not jumpy?

Comment: I guess there is a better way than a timer. Maybe CAAnimation but I'm not sure as I have no experience with it. You also initiating many instances of objects which is time consuming, you should try to update properties instead of creating all again in each rendering cycle

Comment: The issue is probably in how you are setting the current value, which is code that you haven’t shown. Please show that code.  FWIW `timeSeconds` should probably be an `NSTimeInterval` not a `CGFloat`

Comment: What do you mean by this? - are you saying that I am initiating variables that I am then using in the code, when I could just create the new value where it is needed?

Comment: Things like the `UIColor` objects for example. Your `draw` method should have as little code as possible. So create those colour objects once

Comment: That is what I suspected you might be doing. `Timer`s don’t fire particularly accurately, so performing a subtraction like that may well be jumpy. It is better to take a `Date` when the timer starts and then use `timeIntervalSinceNow` to get the elapsed time (subtracting from the target period if you want a count “down” instead of “up”). You can also reduce the complexity of your `draw` function to make it faster. I would also probably use a UILabel rather than drawing the text.

Comment: Paulw11, I have now included the code for how I update the time, if you don't mind taking a look?

Comment: Thanks for your brisk answer Paulw11, it is much appreciated :)

Is it possible that you could include some code to show how the date subtraction would work? - Also, how would I trigger the subtraction - with a timer, still?

Comment: May I also ask Paulw11, about what would happen if they paused the timer, how would the Date thing work then?

Comment: If you want totally smooth changes and your update on each frame can be really fast, why not use CADisplayLink? You can't get smoother than that, because it's tied to the refresh of the physical hardware screen.

Comment: Unfortunately the question was closed before I could add an answer, but [here](https://gist.github.com/paulw11/279bcc3569473a73793da87c163502f3) is some code I created that uses the `TimeInterval` approach with start/pause/stop functionality.  It avoids issues with jitter in `Timer` and gives smooth animation with a time interval of 0.05, using 50% less CPU than running with a time interval of 0.01

Answer (score 2):

You don't actually need a timer for this.  If you use CAShapeLayer you can jsut animate the strokeStart or strokeEnd and the animation system will handle everythign for you.  I have an example playground showing this on my [github](https://github.com/joshuajhomann/RingProgressView), or you can copy and paste below:

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport


class AnimatedRingView: UIView {
    private static let animationDuration = CFTimeInterval(2)
    private let π = CGFloat.pi
    private let startAngle = 1.5 * CGFloat.pi
    private let strokeWidth = CGFloat(8)
    var proportion = CGFloat(0.5) {
        didSet {
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }

    private lazy var circleLayer: CAShapeLayer = {
        let circleLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        circleLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        circleLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        circleLayer.lineWidth = self.strokeWidth
        self.layer.addSublayer(circleLayer)
        return circleLayer
    }()

    private lazy var ringlayer: CAShapeLayer = {
        let ringlayer = CAShapeLayer()
        ringlayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        ringlayer.strokeColor = self.tintColor.cgColor
        ringlayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
        ringlayer.lineWidth = self.strokeWidth
        self.layer.addSublayer(ringlayer)
        return ringlayer
    }()

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        let radius = (min(frame.size.width, frame.size.height) - strokeWidth - 2)/2
        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: startAngle + 2 * π, clockwise: true)
        circleLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath
        ringlayer.path = circlePath.cgPath
        ringlayer.strokeEnd = proportion
    }

    func animateRing(From startProportion: CGFloat, To endProportion: CGFloat, Duration duration: CFTimeInterval = animationDuration) {
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
        animation.duration = duration
        animation.fromValue = startProportion
        animation.toValue = endProportion
        animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut)
        ringlayer.strokeEnd = endProportion
        ringlayer.strokeStart = startProportion
        ringlayer.add(animation, forKey: "animateRing")
    }

}

let view = AnimatedRingView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300))
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view
view.animateRing(From: 0, To: 1)
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I created [SRCountdownTimer](https://github.com/rsrbk/SRCountdownTimer) which does exactly what you are trying to achieve. This is the way I've implemented a timer there:

```
private let fireInterval: TimeInterval = 0.01 // ~60 FPS

/**
 * Starts the timer and the animation. If timer was previously runned, it'll invalidate it.
 * - Parameters:
 *   - beginingValue: Value to start countdown from.
 */
public func start(beginingValue: Int) {
    totalTime = TimeInterval(beginingValue)
    elapsedTime = 0

    timer?.invalidate()
    timer = Timer(timeInterval: fireInterval, repeats: true) { [unowned self] _ in
        self.elapsedTime += self.fireInterval

        if self.elapsedTime < self.totalTime {
            self.setNeedsDisplay() // Will invoke "draw" method to update the progress view
        } else {
            self.end()
        }
    }
    RunLoop.main.add(timer!, forMode: .defaultRunLoopMode)

    delegate?.timerDidStart?()
}
```

So basically every time the timer fires I add the firing interval value to my **elapsedTime**. This makes the countdown work smoothly with 60 FPS.

There is another option suggested in comments about using the **timeIntervalSinceNow** method in **Date** object to calculate the elapsed time by subtracting the timer's beginning timestamp from the current one. Even though this option seems to give you more accurate results I wouldn't recommend you to use it.

The reason is that in this case you gonna calculate the current timestamp every time the timer fires which means every 0.01 second **(!)**. This is way too complex solution and it's much more clever to accept the trade off with not 100% same intervals of timer's fires(however the difference is enough small to not be noticeable for a user).

Comment: FWIW, if you wanted to run a timer for perfect timing for updating UI, you should probably use `CADisplayLink` rather than a `Timer`. Also, rather than incrementing `elapsedTime` by `fireInterval` (which assumes that it will be called without fail, which is not a valid assumption), you should save the start time (e.g. `CACurrentMediaTime()`) before you start the timer or display link and then in the handler, retrieve the current time (again, `CACurrentMediaTime()`) and calculate the elapsed time as the difference between that and the original start time.